# Will laravel reconnect to the database for any where on returned model collection?

Tags: laravel, laravel-collection

If we have a find like this:

```
$returnedModel = Flight::
with("passengers")
->find(1);
```

Now if I add a where on `returnedModel` like this:

```
$returnedModel->passengers()->where("name" , "hamid")->first();
```

Will `Laravel` reconnect to the database for any where on returned model collection?

I added `DB::getQueryLog()` and there is a query with this where! how can I get this without reconnect to database?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to access your `passengers` as a property, not a method, by the way you get a Laravel collection already loaded from the DB (thanks to the `with` eager-loading).

```php
$returnedModel->passengers->firstWhere('name', 'hamid');
```

Comment: Good, But why when I used method, there was a query log?

Comment: Yes because when you use the method, you get an `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany` instance which prepares a query, even if you loaded the relationship earlier.